# Calculate past 3 month average for every past 3rd month

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have a table like this

```
   create table revenue (id varchar(2), trasdate date, revenue int);
   insert into revenue(id, trasdate, revenue)
   values ('aa', '2018/09/01', 1234.5),
   ('aa' , '2018/08/04', 450),
   ('aa', '2018/07/03',500),
   ('aa', '2018/06/04',600),
  ('ab', '2018/09/01', 1234.5),
  ('ab' , '2018/08/04', 450),
    ('ab', '2018/07/03',500),
    ('ab', '2018/06/04',600),
   ('ab', '2018/05/03', 200),
   ('ab', '2018/04/02', 150),
  ('ab', '2018/03/01', 350),
  ('ab', '2018/02/05', 700),
  ('aa', '2018/01/07', 400)
;
```

I am preparing a SQL query to create a SSRS report. I want to calculate a past 3 month average for current and every past 3rd month with result like below. As we are in month of September right now. The result should show something like this:

```
**id    Period  Revenue_3Mon**
aa  March-May   233
aa  June-Aug    516
ab  March-May   233
ab  June-Aug    516
```

Though I can figure out about the Period column. I was mainly focussing on getting the Revenue_3Mon. So I initially tried with the below query after some googling. But this query throws an error as incorrect syntax near 'rows' and if I remove rows from the query then it throws an error as Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'. And incorrect syntax near i.

```
select i.id,i.mon,
   avg([i.mon_revenue]) over (partition by i.id, i.mon order by [i.id], 
  [i.mon] rows between 3  preceding and 1 preceding row) as revenue_3mon -- 
--  using 3 preceding and 1 preceding row you exclude the current row
 from (select a.id, month(a.trasdate) as mon,
         sum(a.revenue) as mon_revenue
  from revenue a
  group by a.id, month(a.trasdate)) i
 group by i.id, i.mon
 order by i.id,i.mon;
```

After few efforts, I gave up on this query and came up with new solution which was a bit close to my expectation (after lots of trial and errors).

```
Declare @count as int;
declare @max as int;
set @count = 4
declare @temp as table (id varchar(2), monthoftrasdate int, revenue int, 
[3monavg] int);
SET @MAX = (SELECT distinct MAX(a.ROWNUM) FROM (SELECT id, month(trasdate) 
 as mon, SUM(revenue) TotalRevenue,
       -- sum(revenue) as mon_revenue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MONTH(TRASDATE)) AS ROWNUM
        FROM revenue
       GROUP BY ID, MONTH(TRASDATE)         
        ) A GROUP BY A.ID);

     while (@count <= @max )
    begin

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT id, month(trasdate) as mon, SUM(revenue) TotalRevenue,
       -- sum(revenue) as mon_revenue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MONTH(TRASDATE)) AS 
ROWNUM
FROM revenue
GROUP BY ID, MONTH(TRASDATE)
 )

  insert into @temp
  SELECT A.ID,A.MON, a.TotalRevenue
    ,( SELECT avg(b.TotalRevenue) as avgrev
    FROM CTE B
    WHERE B.ROWNUM BETWEEN  A.ROWNUM-3 AND A.ROWNUM-1
    AND A.ID = B.ID --AND A.mon = B.mon
    --and b.ROWNUM < a.ROWNUM
    and (a.mon > 3 and a.ROWNUM > 3)
    GROUP BY B.id

    ) AS REVENUE_3MON
  FROM CTE A

 set @count = @count + 1
 end

 select distinct a.* from @temp a
```

The reason I had to use 'distinct' is because the query was showing duplicate records for every id and every month. So far the result shows like below

```
id  MonthofTrasdate Revenue 3MonAvg
aa  1                400    NULL
aa  2                700    NULL
aa  3                350    NULL
aa  4                150    483
aa  5                200    400
aa  6                600    233
aa  7                500    316
aa  8                450    433
aa  9               1234    516
ab  1                400    NULL
ab  2                700    NULL
ab  3                350    NULL
ab  4                150    483
ab  5                200    400
ab  6                600    233
ab  7                500    316
ab  8                450    433
ab  9               1234    516
```

This pulls out past 3 month average for every month. But i will just manipulate the rest on SSRS the way i want it.

As currently my table has no data for previous year. This works for me showing the appropriate result for next couple of months for now. But my concern is when I have to show my boss for next year Jan, Feb and March then it should be able to pull also for these months as well like Oct-Dec (Previous year), Nov-Jan and Dec - Feb. I am struggling to figure out the proper way to put this in my query.

Can you please help me out with this query? And also let me know what is wrong with my former query.

Comment: Why would you want a rolling 3-month period? It is more practical to use quarterly reports if possible. I would ask for clarification on the report contents if this is actually the case. (alternatively do =DateAdd("M",-3,Fields!StartDate.Value) to get the date from 3 months ago for expressions in SSRS)

Comment: Is there always only one record per month (and id)? If there can be multiple revenues per month for an id, how exactly do you define the desired "3-month average" (average of all revenues within the 3 months or the average of the 3 monthly sums)? And finally: where does the 233 for "aa, March-May" come from? I can't find any value for that group in your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your first attempt:

- You enclosed some of the aliases and column names in square brackets like `[i.mon_revenue]`. There is no need for square brackets, but if you want to use them, you have to break them up at the dot: `[i].[mon_revenue]`.
- In your window function expression, there is one *row* too many (in the end).
- Window functions are applied at the very end (after the rest of the respective query), so you also have to include `i.mon_revenue` in your GROUP BY clause of the outer query.
- Knowing that the inner query will produce one row per `id` and `mon`, there will never be preceding rows in an *id-mon* partition. Therefore, you must not partition by both, but only by `id`.

To simplify the query after resolving the issues: ordering by a partition column generally makes no sense, and since - as already mentioned - the inner query returns unique *id-mon* combinations, you don't have to group by these in the outer query. Looking at that query, we see that the outer query just directly selects and uses the values from the inner query, which makes a separation in two queries unneccessary. So, in fact, you wanted to perform the following query, which will produce the rolling 3-month average (I added the monthly `TotalRevenue` as well):

```sql
SELECT id, MONTH(trasdate) AS mon, SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
   AVG(SUM(revenue)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY MONTH(trasdate) ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS revenue_3mon
FROM revenue
GROUP BY id, MONTH(trasdate)
ORDER BY id, MONTH(trasdate);
```

Suggestions on your second attempt:

- When calculating the `@MAX` value, you rely on the fact that each `id` has revenues for the same number of months. Are you sure?
- The code inside the WHILE loop does not depend on `@count`, so it will add the same data into the `@temp` table multiple times, which is probably the reason why you thought you needed a DISTINCT. Therfore: No need for the variables, no need for a loop and a `@temp`, no need for DISTINCT.
- The conditions `A.mon > 3` and `A.rownum > 3` are redundant with your current data. In general, I guess, you don't want to explicitly excluse the months from January to March, so `A.mon > 3` should be removed. `A.rownum > 3` could be removed, too, unless you really don't want to see a 3-month average when there are only 2 preceding months or less.
- As the subquery for the average is restricted to only one `id`, there's no need for a GROUP BY.
- Since the `ROW_NUMBER` function doesn't care about gaps in the months, I suggest to use a different numbering function, for example `DATEDIFF(month, MAX(trasdate), GETDATE()) AS mnum`. Of course, the comparison in the WHERE clause of the subquery then has to be changed to `B.mnum BETWEEN A.mnum+1 AND A.mnum+3`.

So, your second attempt can be reduced to this, which will produce the same result as the above, at least with your sample data, where no gaps in the months exist:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id, MONTH(trasdate) AS mon, SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
        DATEDIFF(month, MAX(trasdate), GETDATE()) AS mnum
    FROM revenue
    GROUP BY id, MONTH(trasdate)
)
SELECT id, mon, TotalRevenue
  , (SELECT AVG(B.TotalRevenue)
     FROM CTE B
     WHERE B.mnum BETWEEN A.mnum+1 AND A.mnum+3
       AND A.id = B.id
    ) AS revenue_3mon
FROM CTE A
ORDER BY id, mnum DESC;
```

Now, guess what, an expression like my `mnum` using `DATEDIFF` increases by one every month as we move to the past, regardless of a change of years, so this might be useful for grouping as well, whether you want to (or can?) use Window functions or not:

**With OVER()**

```
SELECT id, MONTH(MIN(trasdate)) AS mon, YEAR(MIN(trasdate)) AS yr, SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
   AVG(SUM(revenue)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY MIN(trasdate) ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS revenue_3mon
FROM revenue
GROUP BY id, DATEDIFF(month, trasdate, GETDATE())
ORDER BY id, DATEDIFF(month, trasdate, GETDATE()) DESC;
```

**Without OVER()**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id, MIN(trasdate) AS min_dt, SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
        DATEDIFF(month, trasdate, GETDATE()) AS mnum
    FROM revenue
    GROUP BY id, DATEDIFF(month, trasdate, GETDATE())
)
SELECT id, MONTH(min_dt) AS mon, YEAR(min_dt) AS yr, TotalRevenue
  , (SELECT AVG(B.TotalRevenue)
     FROM CTE B
     WHERE B.mnum BETWEEN A.mnum+1 AND A.mnum+3
       AND A.id = B.id
    ) AS revenue_3mon
FROM CTE A
ORDER BY id, mnum DESC;
```

Both queries allow for retrieving the minimum and maximum date for each period (including month and year).

If you instead wanted what you originally posted under *The result should show something like this* (just grouping by previous 3-months intervals), you just would have to group your original `revenue` table by `id` and `(DATEDIFF(month, trasdate, GETDATE())-1)/3` (filtering `WHERE DATEDIFF(month, trasdate, GETDATE()) > 0`). If so, this kind of grouping and aggregation could, of course, be done also by the Report Server.

Comment: Hi Kais, using your With over() example also giving me same error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'

Comment: It seems that you don't have at least SQL Server 2012, so you could use the other version. Otherwise both version should work, I have tested them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want:

```
select r.*,
       avg(r.mon_revenue) over (partition by r.id
                                order by r.mon_min
                                rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding row
                               ) as revenue_3mon 
--  using 3 preceding and 1 preceding row you exclude the current row
 from (select r.id, month(r.trasdate) as mon,
              min(r.trasdate) as mon_min,
              sum(r.revenue) as mon_revenue
       from revenue r
       group by r.id, year(r.trasdate), month(r.trasdate)
      ) 4
order by r.id, r.mon, r.mon_min;
```

Notes:

- I fixed the code so it recognizes years as well as dates.
- The expression `[i.mon_revenue]` is not a valid column reference (in your case).  You have no column with the name "i.mon_revenue" (with the `.` in the name).
- I changed the column alias to `r` to match the table.
- I added a date column for each month to make it easier to express the ordering.
- The outer `group by` is not necessary.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I appreciate your help but this query too is throwing similar error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'rows'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'sum'.

Comment: Just a reminder that I am using SQL Server 2014. This windows function is not working in this version for some reason.

Comment: @inquest . . . Window functions work fine in SQL Server 2014 (unless you have some old compatibility mode set).  The problem was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in your code. This should give you what you need. The inner query is the important bit but hopefully this will be enough to get you on your way.

I switch our the temp table for variable and changed the revenue column to not be INT as you have decimal values in there but other than that your original sample table is unchanged

```
   DECLARE @revenue table (id varchar(2), trasdate date, revenue float)
   insert into @revenue(id, trasdate, revenue)
   values ('aa', '2018/09/01', 1234.5),
   ('aa' , '2018/08/04', 450),
   ('aa', '2018/07/03',500),
   ('aa', '2018/06/04',600),
  ('ab', '2018/09/01', 1234.5),
  ('ab' , '2018/08/04', 450),
    ('ab', '2018/07/03',500),
    ('ab', '2018/06/04',600),
   ('ab', '2018/05/03', 200),
   ('ab', '2018/04/02', 150),
  ('ab', '2018/03/01', 350),
  ('ab', '2018/02/05', 700),
  ('aa', '2018/01/07', 400)

SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        ( 
          SELECT 
                *
                , MONTH(trasdate) as MonthNumber
                , AVG(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                     ORDER BY 
                                        id
                                        , MONTH(trasdate) ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as ThreeMonthAvg
            FROM @revenue
        ) a
    WHERE MONTH(GETDATE()) - MonthNumber IN (0, 3, 6, 9)
```

This gives the following results

```
aa  2018-06-04  600     6   400
aa  2018-09-01  1234.5  9   516.666666666667
ab  2018-03-01  350     3   700
ab  2018-06-04  600     6   233.333333333333
ab  2018-09-01  1234.5  9   516.666666666667
```

Comment: There is same error message for this query as well. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'. Any idea how can i fix this error?

Comment: What compatibility level is your database?

Comment: Hi Alan,compatibility level is SQL Server 2008 (100). There are only three options in the dropdown 2000, 2005, 2008

Comment: Are you sure that you have sql2012? What server version are you running?